# Changing values of boolean Array programmatically

Tags: android, boolean

I would like to know if there would be a possible way to change the values of the boolean array I have set up:

```
boolean[] checked = new boolean[]{true, false, true, false, true};
```

Would I be able to programmatically change these values individually? I know you can do `Arrays.fill(array, true);` to fill all of them, but what about individually? thanks

Comment: so what do you have problems with?

Comment: changing a final object is not possible

Comment: @Opiatefuchs That wasn't supposed to be there, i've removed it from my question now.

Comment: ok, then follow nr4bt´s answer....thats correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the value simply by accessing array element via index. 
An array is a java object, thus by declaring final, you can not assign a new reference but values still can be changed.

```
final boolean[] checked = new boolean[]{true, false, true, false, true};

System.out.println(checked[0]);   //output : true

checked[0] = false;

System.out.println(checked[0]);   //output : false
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class Boolean {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    final boolean[] checked = new boolean[]{true, false, true, false, true};

    for(int i=0; i<checked.length;i++){

        if(checked[i]==true){
            checked[i]=false;
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(checked[i]));

        }else{
            checked[i]=true;
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(checked[i]));
        }
    }

    return;

}
```

}